# Reading SharePoint list items using REST API and knockoutJS

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest

I have used below code for getting list items from SharePoint list. Output is coming in alerts but it is not displayed in HTML controls.

```
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/knockout/knockout-2.2.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script>

    function insightViewModel() {
        var self = this;

        self.insights = ko.observableArray();
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://demo/Dev/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('CountryNames')/items",
                type: "GET",
                headers: {
                    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                },
                success:suc,
                error: function (error) {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(error));
                    }

                });

            function suc(data)
                {
                alert(data.d.results);
                r=data.d.results;
                alert(r[1].CountryName);

                                for(var i=0;i<5;i++)
                                    {
                                                          self.insights.push({
                                                           Title:ko.observable(r[i].Title), 
                                                           CountryName:ko.observable(r[i].CountryName)
                                                           });
                                 alert(r[i].CountryName);
                                     }
                }

                            }           

         ko.applyBindings(new insightViewModel());

</script>
<body>
    <table>
    <thead>
        <tr><th>Title</th><th>Name</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach:insights">
        <tr>

            <td data-bind="text:CountryName"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the output of data.d.results from sharepoint site. I have used this code in script editor.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine, check this fiddle: [http://jsfiddle.net/n869w8yh/](http://jsfiddle.net/n869w8yh/1/)

I replaced your request to SharePoint with a example array.

Just make sure you type the names of the fields correctly, don't forget case sensitivity. The for-loop is hard coded to 5 items in your code, do you have 5 items in that list?

**EDIT:**

Finally got some time to test this in a script editor. Try this in your code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  ko.applyBindings(new insightViewModel());
});
```

Comment: yes I have 5 items

Comment: Could you update the question with the result you're getting back from SharePoint? I would like to see what's in `data.d.result`.

Comment: I see that you have updated the question with the result of data.d.results. I should have been more precise, how does one of those object look? Do they contain both the attributes CountryName AND Title?

You can use `JSON.stringify(data.d.results[0])` 
**or** 
`alert(data.d.results[0].CountryName + " - " + data.d.results[0].Title);`

Comment: I have used this, " alert(data.d.results[0].CountryName + " - " + data.d.results[0].Title);  "  and it is giving me the results like                     " india - hello"  from sharepoint list

Comment: @vikashkumar please see my updated answer.